# how to unzip the file from s3 using EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have 150 GB file in s3,I would like to unzip and upload the each file back to s3.what is the best approach to do with python and EC2 ? I appreciate your response.

Comment: What would be the "trigger" for this process? Do you want it to happen immediately after somebody uploads a file, or will the process be triggered at regular intervals, or perhaps when somebody specifically requests it? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download it on your system
2. Unzip the folder and it will create a normal folder say "Unzipped_Folder"
3. Assuming you are using Windows, install aws-cli in that.
4. Create an IAM User with S3 write access to that bucket and create a Access and Secret Access Key.
5. In aws-cli add the credentials from command prompt.
   $ aws configure
6. Now run the following command to send files to S3 bucket
   $ aws s3 cp your_directory_path s3://your_bucket_name --recursive